# Is there any command attribute for label in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know that there is command attribute available for button widget,but it is not available for label widget.I need to perform certain action when a label is clicked on root window.Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504571/clickable-tkinter-labels Duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `label.bind("<Button-1>", ...`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def command(event):
    print("hi")

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(text="Click me!", width=50, height=10, master=root)
label.pack()
label.bind("<Button-1>", command)
```